# Using pathlib with dataframe

Tags: python, pathlib

I have a dataframe with file paths and file names

I am trying to use this code to iterate through the dataframe and print the file name

the following works when I test the actual pathname  and filename that is in the dataframe columns

```
from pathlib import Path
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for path in Path('Z:\\A\\2021-07-21\\DL\\').rglob('xx_240721_21*_AT_B.txt.bz2'):
        print(path)
```

When i try and parse the actual values using the dataframe values, it does not work

```
from pathlib import Path
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    search = df['Search2']
    filename = df['filename']
    for path in Path('Search').rglob('filename'):
        print(path)
```

I can confirm that the Search2 and filename have the exact strings as what I was testing with

Still new to python so any help will be helpful.As always, I have tried to do some research on this but got stuck

Comment: You are passing in `Search` and `filename` as string literals, rather than using the values of the similarly named variables in your second piece of code. Are you sure that is what you meant?

Comment: If not, you'll probably want to do something with the dataframe you loop over as well. Right now the data in each row is not processed at all. Don't you mean to get the `search` and `filename` values from the current `row`?

Comment: hey, thanks,. my bad on that. I have put it inside the  loop but still doesnt seem to parse to the path('search') and ('filename'). im using  for path in Path('search').rglob('filename'):.  is this a syntax issue? forgive my nooby queries.

Comment: Please look up what a string literal is, and then think about whether that is what you meant to use in `for path in Path(...).rglob(...):`.

Comment: what i have in my dataframe are actual strings of the full path an the filename. eg 'Z:\\A\\2021-07-21\\DL\\'  and 'A210721_14*_ATO_B.txt.bz2'.  I thought i should be able to pass these as strings? How can i get the value eg using the df[Search2] inside path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out and used the following

```
from pathlib import Path
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    search = (row['Search2'])
    filename= (row['filename'])
    for path in Path(search).rglob(filename):
        print(path.name)
```